# Incoming Mails in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, incoming-mail

I have a Document Library that receives a mail every week. I want to show the list of mails with their summaries. Is it possible to get that mail's content in Sharepoint, without deploying a custom code?

Thanks.

Edit 1:
Anyone? Anywhere? :(

Edit 2: Incoming E-Mail Settings:
http://i39.tinypic.com/23m1u7l.png

By summary, I mean, say two lines of body of the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about AJAX?

I can get the received mails' path (path to EML files, actually) and maybe i can use AJAX to query each EML file, to get its content?

Answering my own question is, weird.

Comment: It's funny you asked this. I was wondering this very same thing the other day. EML files open as HTML in some browsers, so this *might* work. Let me know how it works if you do try it!

Comment: I'm afraid AJAX will cause performance problems as the number of list items increases.

If one of the conditions wasn't *without deploying a custom code*, I would suggest overriding `SPItemEventReceiver.ItemAdded` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx to get email's body from an EML file and save it to a custom column.

Comment: List will be limited to n<10 items. I wish i could use custom code, but the it is impossible in my situation since the company providing Sharepoint service costs even deploying your code.